# Should `docker run` be avoided, to execute an image created with `docker-compose`?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, orchestration

I've checked on SO but couldn't find a exhaustive answer.

My `docker-composer.yml` defines few things including *volumes*

```
app:
    volumes:
        - "./:/app"
    ...
```

If I use `docker run` to instance the image, then I will need to specify **again** the same *volumes* specified in `docker-compose.yml`.

```
docker run -v "./:/app"
```

That *might* be desirable for some use cases, but in general having the same definition specified in 2 different places is not really maintainable (or obvious for future devs). I'd like to avoid defining the same config in different locations (one for `docker-compose` and one as arguments for `docker run`).

Can it be stated that if configuring *volumes* (or others parameters) inside `docker-compose.yml` then, in order to have them, the image **should** be run via `docker-compose up` rather than `docker run -v redundant:volume:specification`?

**Note:** I am asking about best practices more than personal opinions.

Answer (score 1):

You should think of the `docker-compose.yml` as not unlike a very specialized shell script that runs `docker run` for you.  It's not a bad idea to try to minimize the number of require mounts and options (for example, don't bind-mount code over the code in your image) but it's also not especially a best practice to say "this is only runnable via *this* `docker-compose.yml` file".

Also consider that there are other ways to run a container, with different syntaxes.  Both [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io) and Hashicorp's [Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io) have *very* different syntaxes, and can't reuse the `docker-compose.yml`.  If you're running the image in a different context, you'll basically have to rewrite this configuration anyways.

In limited scopes – "for this development project, in this environment, in this specific repository" – it's reasonable enough to say "the standard way to run this with standard options is via `docker-compose up`", but it's still possible to run the image a different way if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

In general one *should* rely on `docker-compose`, once starting to use it, since just relying on `docker <cmd>` might miss some configuration and give unexpected results (especially if freshly landing on the project and not having confidence with it).

Executing the images with `docker run` will lead to the following disadvantages:

- having to **remember** adding eventual parameters **at each run**, that are instead implicit into with `docker-compose`
- even when remembering, or having a bash script calling `docker run` with the right parameters, future changes to these parameters will need to be reflected in two different places. This is **not very maintainable and error prone**.
- eventual other **correlated images will not run** and one has to remember to run them manually; or add them into a script, ending again with definition in two different places.

However, for a broader view considering other runners (k8s) check [David Maze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze).